# Weak and strong convergence of sequence of linear functionals

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

Is this sequence of linear functionals weakly (strongly) convergent : $$f_n((x_j))=\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{x_k}{k}} , (x_j) \in \ell_2\,?$$

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** show that for $\{x_n\}\subset\ell^2$, $\{x_n\}$ converges weakly to $0$ if and only if the following two conditions are realized:

1. the sequence $\{x_n\}$ is bounded in $\ell^2$.
2. Denoting $e_k$ the sequence for which all terms are $0$, except the $k$-th which is $1$, we have $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\langle x_n,e_k\rangle =0$ for each $k$.

Comment: @Norbert спасибо for editing!

Comment: You are wellcome! Nice to see your efforts in study russian :)

Comment: @Davide Giraudo So, we have that ${x_n}$ converges weakly to $0$ iff $|x_k|$ tends to $0$. Then $f_n$ converges weakly to $f=0$. And for strong convergence $${ |f_n(x)|=|\sum_{k=1}^{n}{\frac{x_k}{k}}|\leq \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{x_k^2} \cdot \sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{1/k^2}}=||x||\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}{1/k^2}}}=||x||\frac{\pi}{\sqrt{6}}$$ => $||f_n||=\frac{\Pi}{\sqrt{6}}\neq 0$. Then there is no strong convergence. Is it right?

Comment: You have checked the sequence $\{f_n\}$ is bounded, and that $f_n(e_k)\to 0$ for all $k$ so yes, you can conclude to weak convergence (the choice of the notation of $x_k$ in may answer is, I recognize, quite misleading). You can actually compute the norm of $f_n$ in order to see there is no strong convergence.