# Limit of sequence of linear functionals

Tags: functional-analysis

Determine whether the following sequence of functionals over $l_2$

$$\phi_n(x) = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt k\ x_k\ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ \ x = (x_1, x_2, x_3,...)$$

converges in the weak sense (i.e. $\exists \phi \in l_2^{*} : \forall x  \in  l_2 : \lim_{n\to \infty}\phi_n(x)= \phi(x) $),

in the strong sense (i.e. $\exists \phi \in l_2^{*} : \lim_{n\to \infty}||\phi_n-\phi||=0$),

and in case there is some kind of convergence, find the limit.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Partial only (don't have much time, and needs checking): "Weak sense" (pointwise convergence). Try Cauchy-Schwarz, the usual suspect: for any $x\in\ell_2[0,1]$,
$$
\sum_{k=1}^n \left\lvert\frac{\sqrt{k}}{n}x_k\right\rvert
\leq \sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n^2}}\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^n x_k^2}
\leq \sqrt{\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{k}{n}}\sqrt{\sum_{k=1}^\infty x_k^2}
\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\lVert x \rVert_2^2<\infty
$$
using the Riemann sum.

You therefore have absolute convergence, and therefore absolute convergence of
$\frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=1}^n \sqrt{k}x_k$.

Comment: As the Riemann sum converges to $\int_0^1 x dx = \frac{1}{2}$.

Comment: This suggests that $||\phi_n||$ approaches $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, what do you do next?

Comment: No, this proves that $\lim_{n\to\infty} \phi_n(x)$ exists (for any $x$). Since this amounts to proving that the series $\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{\sqrt{k}}{n}x_k$ converges, and the above shows (by monotone convergence) it's absolutely convergent -- hence convergent.

Comment: Oh, now I see, thank you. But still it remains to find the limit.

Comment: Yes, and to deal with the strong convergence case.

Comment: A very quick comment: if $\sqrt{n} x_n \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \ell$ (say $\ell=0$), then by Césaro $\phi_n(x) \xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{} \ell$ as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\ell_2^*\cong\ell_2$ we may identify each $\phi_n$ with $f_n=(\sqrt{1}/n,\sqrt{2}/n,\ldots,\sqrt{n}/n,0,\ldots)\in\ell_2$. Therefore

- $\Vert\phi_n\Vert=\Vert f_n\Vert=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}\sqrt{\frac{n+1}{n}}\leq 1$
- $\lim_{n\to\infty}\phi_n(e_k)=\lim_{n\to\infty}f_n(k)=0$.

Using [this criterion](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/325568/weak-and-strong-convergence-of-sequence-of-linear-functionals) we conclude that $\phi_n$ weakly converges to 0.

This sequence is not norm convergent. Otherwise, we would have $\lim_{n\to\infty}\Vert\phi_n\Vert=0$, but in fact $\lim_{n\to\infty}\Vert\phi_n\Vert=2^{-1/2}$.

Comment: The criterion you mentioned can also be justified in the following way: since the norm of all $\phi_n$ is bounded by some $M>0$, then the pointwise limit $\lim_{n\to \infty}\phi_n(x)$ is a bounded linear functional, therefore continuous. And since the limit functional equals 0 over all finite linear combinations of $\{ e_k\}$, it has to be 0 everywhere, because finite linear combinations of $\{ e_k\}$ are dense in $l_2$.